# Socket event is resetting state array in react

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

On server side I have this nodejs app:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    socket.name = socket.handshake.headers.name;
    socket.room = socket.handshake.headers.room;
    socket.user_id = socket.handshake.headers.user_id;
    return next();
});

let all_sockets = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const ob = {
        id: socket.id,
        room: socket.room,
        name: socket.name,
        user_id: socket.user_id
    };
    all_sockets = all_sockets.filter(el => el.user_id !== socket.user_id);
    all_sockets.push(ob);
    socket.on("message", (data) => {
        const recipients = all_sockets.filter(el => el.room === socket.room && el.id !== socket.id);
        recipients.forEach(el => {
            io.to(el.id).emit('private', data);
        })
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
        all_sockets = all_sockets.filter(el => el.id !== socket.id);
    });
});
```

On client side I have this component:

```
const Chat = () => {
    const { username } = useParams();
    const socket_url = `http://localhost:4000/`;
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);

    const sendMessage = () => {
        const msg = messageRef.current.value;
        const message_object = {from: username, data: msg};
        setChatMessages([...chatMessages, message_object]);
        socket.emit('message', msg);
        messageRef.current.value = '';
    }


    const connect = async () => {
        try {
            const body = {username: username};
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login`, body);
            const data = await response.json();
            const sck = io(socket_url, {
                path: "/socket.io",
                autoConnect: true,
                extraHeaders: {
                    room: data.user.room,
                    user_id: data.user._id,
                    name: data.user.name
                }
            });
            sck.on('private', function(msg) {
                const message_object = {from: 'user', data: msg};
                setChatMessages([...chatMessages, message_object]);
            });
            setSocket(sck);
        }
        catch(exception){
            console.log("exception",exception);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      connect();
    }, []);

    const messageRef = useRef('');

    return (
        <div>
          <div>
              <div>
                  {
                      JSON.stringify(chatMessages)
                  }
              </div>
              <div>
                  <input ref={messageRef} type="text" placeholder="Enter message"/>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button onClick={sendMessage} >Send</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
}
```

I open a browser window with user1 and another browser window with user2 and I type 3 messages from user1:

```
one
two
three
```

user1 sees this on the screen:

```
[{"from":"user1","data":"one"},{"from":"user1","data":"two"},{"from":"user1","data":"three"}]
```

However, user2 will see all the time that "chatMessages" is resetted. So after the thirth message, uer2 sees:

```
[{"from":"user","data":"three"}]
```

If user1 will enter "four", then user2 would see:

```
[{"from":"user","data":"four"}]
```

Also, when user2 types: "hello", then user1 will see on the screen:

```
[{"from":"user","data":"hello"}]
```

Why is the state array getting resetted? This happens only from inside the received function here:

```
sck.on('private', function(msg) {
    const message_object = {from: 'user', data: msg};
    setChatMessages([...chatMessages, message_object]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chatMessages` is closure captured. It always holds the same "value" it had during "on" attachment. Try using [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). (And better to use it in both places, in the `sck.on` and `sendMessage` functions.)

```js
setChatMessages(curr => [...curr, message_object]);
```